# How can i change the Image to be in the same size of the pictureBox?

Tags: c#

I have this function:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b))
                {
                    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                    g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
                }

                return b;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

But how do i use what to put in the Size size ? 
I tried to call the function like: ResizeImage(bitmap,new Size(100,100));
But that;s not the way.

In Form1 i did:

```
bitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\ffmpegtorun\ffmpeg-20130509-git-13cb6ed-win32-static\bin\Screenshots\Screenshot000000.jpg");
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

Since everything is blurry inside the pictureBox also if it's Zoom mode or Stretchimage mode i thought to resize the image to the size of the pictureBox and maybe change the pictureBox mode to Normal ot stretchimage ? I'm not sure how to fix this blurry in the pictureBox.

I'm adding a screenshot here of my magnifier glass which is working good but only show blurry when moving over the pictureBox.

This is when it's in Stretchimage mode but it's the same when it's also set to Zoom mode:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!269&authkey=!AHI8lMsnZHfka60

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Magnifier20070401
{
    public partial class MagnifierForm : Form
    {
        private bool _doMove;

        public MagnifierForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _doMove = true;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
            TopMost = true;
            Width = 150;
            Height = 150;
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            gp.AddEllipse(ClientRectangle);
            Region = new Region(gp);
            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.Enabled = true;
            mTimer.Interval = 20;
            mTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(HandleTimer);
            mScreenImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            mStartPoint = new Point(500, 500);
            mTargetPoint = new Point(500, 500);
            speed = 0.35F;
            zoom = 3.0F;
            hidecursor = false;
            hue = 30;
        }

        public MagnifierForm(bool MoveTheGlass, bool InTaskBar, int MagnifierWidth, int MagnifierHeight, Point MagnifierStartPoint, float SpeedFactor, float ChangeZoom, bool HideMouseCursor, float AdjustHue)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            TopMost = true;
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            gp.AddEllipse(ClientRectangle);
            Region = new Region(gp);
            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.Enabled = true;
            mTimer.Interval = 20;
            mTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(HandleTimer);
            mScreenImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            _doMove = MoveTheGlass;
            ShowInTaskbar = InTaskBar;
            Width = MagnifierWidth;
            Height = MagnifierHeight;
            mStartPoint = MagnifierStartPoint;
            mTargetPoint = MagnifierStartPoint;
            speed = SpeedFactor;
            zoom = ChangeZoom;
            hidecursor = HideMouseCursor;
            hue = AdjustHue;
        }

        protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
        {
            RepositionAndShow();
        }

        private delegate void RepositionAndShowDelegate();

        private void RepositionAndShow()
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new RepositionAndShowDelegate(RepositionAndShow));
            }
            else
            {
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mScreenImage);
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(mScreenImage.Width, mScreenImage.Height));
                HSLAdjust.BitmapFunctions bf = new HSLAdjust.BitmapFunctions((Bitmap)mScreenImage);
                bf.Hue(hue);
                bf.Dispose();
                g.Dispose();

                if (hidecursor == true)
                {
                    Cursor.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
                }
                Capture = true;
                mCurrentPoint = Cursor.Position;
                Show(); // to add here the bool of the Mouse Cursor to hide or not to hide
            }
        }

        void HandleTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float dx = speed * (mTargetPoint.X - mCurrentPoint.X);
            float dy = speed * (mTargetPoint.Y - mCurrentPoint.Y);

            if (mFirstTime)
            {
                mFirstTime = false;

                mCurrentPoint.X = mTargetPoint.X;
                mCurrentPoint.Y = mTargetPoint.Y;

                Left = (int)mCurrentPoint.X - Width / 2;
                Top = (int)mCurrentPoint.Y - Height / 2;

                return;
            }

            mCurrentPoint.X += dx;
            mCurrentPoint.Y += dy;

            if (Math.Abs(dx) < 1 && Math.Abs(dy) < 1)
            {
                mTimer.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Update location
                Left = (int)mCurrentPoint.X - Width / 2;
                Top = (int)mCurrentPoint.Y - Height / 2;
                mLastMagnifierPosition = new Point((int)mCurrentPoint.X, (int)mCurrentPoint.Y);
            }

            Refresh();
        }


        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mOffset = new Point(Width / 2 - e.X, Height / 2 - e.Y);
            mCurrentPoint = PointToScreen(new Point(e.X + mOffset.X, e.Y + mOffset.Y));
            mTargetPoint = mCurrentPoint;
            mTimer.Enabled = true;

        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_doMove == true)
            {
                mTargetPoint = PointToScreen(new Point(e.X + mOffset.X, e.Y + mOffset.Y));
                mTimer.Enabled = true;
            }

        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            /*if (mConfiguration.DoubleBuffered)
            {
                // Do not paint background (required for double buffering)!
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnPaintBackground(e);
            }*/
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        }

        protected override void  OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mBufferImage == null)
            {
                mBufferImage = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            }
            Graphics bufferGrf = Graphics.FromImage(mBufferImage);

            Graphics g;

            /*if (mConfiguration.DoubleBuffered)
            {
                g = bufferGrf;
            }
            else
            {*/
                g = e.Graphics;
            //}

            if (mScreenImage != null)
            {
                Rectangle dest = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
                int w = (int)(Width / zoom);//mConfiguration.ZoomFactor);
                int h = (int)(Height / zoom);//mConfiguration.ZoomFactor);
                int x = Left - w / 2 + Width / 2;
                int y = Top - h / 2 + Height / 2;

                g.DrawImage(
                    mScreenImage,
                    dest,
                    x, y,
                    w, h,
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(mBufferImage, 0, 0, Width, Height);      
        }


        //--- Data Members ---
        #region Data Members
        private bool hidecursor;
        private float zoom;
        private float hue;
        private float speed;
        private Timer mTimer;
        private Image mBufferImage = null;
        private Image mScreenImage = null;
        private Point mStartPoint;
        private PointF mTargetPoint;
        private PointF mCurrentPoint;
        private Point mOffset;
        private bool mFirstTime = true;
        private static Point mLastMagnifierPosition = Cursor.Position;
        #endregion


        // New code \\

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);

            Point pt = Control.MousePosition;
            int eX = pt.X - this.Left;
            int eY = pt.Y - this.Top;

            mOffset = new Point(0, 0);
            mCurrentPoint = PointToScreen(new Point(eX + mOffset.X, eY + mOffset.Y));
            mTargetPoint = mCurrentPoint;
            mTimer.Enabled = true;
            this.Capture = true;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);

            if (_doMove)
            {
                Left = (int)mCurrentPoint.X - Width / 2;
                Top = (int)mCurrentPoint.Y - Height / 2;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
            if (_doMove == true)
            {
                _doMove = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _doMove = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the magnifier glass Form code so maybe someone can test it and see how blurry it is when moving over the pictureBox.

This is how i turn on/off the magnifier glass in Form1.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.M))
            {
                if (mf == null)
                {
                    mf = new Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm();
                    mf.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                    mf.Location = Control.MousePosition;
                    mf.Show();

                    this.Select();
                }
                else if (mf.IsDisposed)
                {
                    mf = new Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm();
                    mf.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                    mf.Location = Control.MousePosition;
                    mf.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    mf.Close();
                    mf = null;
                }
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Looks like it should do the job to me.

Comment: VisualMelon maybe i didn't ask the right question in the topic. The reason i wanted to change the image size to the pictureBox size is that the image in the pictureBox is blurry even in Zoom mode or Stretchimage mode. I have updated my question now with a link to an image show what happen when i move over the pictureBox with the magnifier glass i'm using. And if i move with it over the Form area or the screen area the magnifer zoom everything smooth. But only when i move over the pictureBox area it's blurry.

Comment: Seems to work nicely for me - your image shows the magnifier in front of some already horribly aliased text, is this the case? If so the magnifier can only scale up the pixels behind it at whatever resolution they are already at.

Comment: VisualMan no if i edit the screenshot000000.jpg with the program paint i can zoom it resize it very large more then 1920X1080 which is the original resolution and i see the text very clear. And since the magnifier glass show the text good enough on the Form are and around the screen area so i guess the problem is with the pictureBox.

Comment: VisualMan if i set the pictureBox1 mode to Normal then the magnifier glass on it showe the text and everything in the pictureBox smooth. But then again on Normal mode i don't see the whole image in the pictureBox it dosen't fit right. If i use stretchimage or zoom then it's blurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the picturebox sizemode to zoom

`PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;`

Comment: James the problem with Zoom is that the pictureBox is much smaller now. Second everything inside is Blurry/Blur. What i'm doing is using a magnifier glass and when i move over the pictureBox are it's making zoom in to the text to the graphics inside but everything is blurry ! If i move the magnifier glass over the screen or over the Form everything looks good sharp smooth. But only when i move over the pictureBox1 area it's blurry can't see anything . So i thought to make the image size the same as the pictureBox. Making it zoom still make it blurry.

Comment: I added now the magnifier zoom Form code so maybe someone can test it and see how blurry it is when moving over the pictureBox area.